# error reading information on service hiawatha: No such file or directory

Tags: centos5, kloxo, hiawatha

I want to install kloxo-mr panel.
my os is centos 5.9

I did the setup steps according to this guide:

https://github.com/mustafaramadhan/kloxo/blob/dev/how-to-install.txt

During the installation process it show me this error and end install Unsuccessfully.

```
Creating Vpopmail database...
Prepare /home/kloxo/httpd...
error reading information on service hiawatha: No such file or directory
sh: hiawatha: command not found
```

what I must do for solving this problem ??

Comment: please someone help me !!!!1 :(((((((((

Answer (score 0):

Don't care about it. It's just 'false positive'. Latest update already handle this issue.